# Overriding function with exact same content causes error

Tags: java, eclipse

The title may be a bit misleading but I was not sure how to word this.

I have 2 classes, **BinarySearchTree** and **HashTreeSet**.

I am currently using HashTreeSet to implement a variant of BinarySearchTree using different sorts, compares and such.

Info:

- BinarySearchTree is fully functional
- HashTreeSet extends BinarySearchTree
- Both classes contains at the bottom a **Node**-class which represents each node in the tree

I have one problem and one problem only so far: HashTreeSet complains about my find(T target) function, saying the return-type `Node<T>` is incompatible with `BinarySearchTree<T>.find(T)`.

**BinarySearchTree** implements the method *find(T target)*.

I wanted to change some of the *find*-code in the HashTreeSet class, so I copied the function over, but now it complains about some return-statement.

I'll post parts of the code to avoid clutter, let me know if you want the full versions:

**HashTreeSet**

```
public class HashTreeSet<T extends Comparable<T>> extends BinarySearchTree<T> implements SimpleSet<T> {
  /*
   * Other functions
   */


  The error is highlighted here, see error message below
           |
           |
           V 
  public Node<T> find(T target) {
    Node<T> current = findAgain(target, root);

    if( current == null )
      return null;

    return current;
  }
  private Node<T> findAgain(T target, Node<T> next){
    // Stuff
  } 
  class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    // Stuff
  }
}
```

**BinarySearchTree**

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> implements SimpleSet<T> {

  /*
   * Other functions
   */
  public Node<T> find(T target) {
    Node<T> current = findAgain(target, root);

    if( current == null )
      return null;

    return current;
  }
  private Node<T> findAgain(T target, Node<T> next){
    // Stuff
  } 
  class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    // Stuff
  }
}
```

**Error**

> The return type is incompatible with BinarySearchTree.find(T)

When I attempt to QuickFix it, it changes the return-statement from `Node<T>` to `treestuff.Node<T>` but it still remain red and uncompilable. `treestuff` is the package in which both of these files are contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two different `Node<T>` classes - one as an inner class of `BinarySearchTree` and one as an inner class of `HashTreeSet`. They're completely different classes, so your override is trying to return an unrelated type to the return type of the original method... it's no wonder the compiler it complaining.

Do you *need* two different types? I would hope not - but if you really do, make `HashTreeSet.Node` extend `BinarySearchTree.Node`. I'd personally recommend pulling out the `Node` type as a top-level class, too - that will make the code simpler in other respects.

Additionally, it's not really clear that `HashTreeSet` should extend `BinarySearchTree` at all - typically you have a binary tree *or* you use hashing... not both. Are you *sure* that your inheritance here is appropriate?

Comment: The reason I have two different inner Node classes if because their compareTo functions, among others, differ. Can/should I extend an inner class?

Comment: @krystah: I think you *can*, but you should really think about whether you *want* to. I would try to avoid inner classes as far as possible, and think really carefully about whether your inheritance hierarchy is actually sensible to start with.

Comment: The reason I'm extending is because the differences aren't meant to be as big as they may sound. I mainly want to make the sorting happen by hashCodes rather than object data values.

Comment: @krystah: Sorting by hash codes sounds like a recipe for disaster. I'm mentally running away screaming at this point. If you *really* want to do that, just make your `BinarySearchTree` accept a `Comparator<T>` for custom comparisons. But be *very, very* aware that you're doing something non-sensical and dangerous. Consider hash collisions, for example...

Comment: Yeah, I learned yesterday here at SO the dangers and frequencies of hashCode collision, but this is an assignment from my professor, and the requirements states A: Objects are stored in a binary search tree, B: Objects are sorted by hashCodes. So while I agree that it sounds rather weird, it's unfortunately a requirement!

Comment: @krystah: Aargh. Well, as I say, I would change your `BinarySearchTree` to accept a `Comparator<T>` which means you can separate the search tree logic from "how two items are compared".